# Using python-social-auth with linkedin

Tags: python, django, linkedin-api

Hi I'm using python social auth to allow user sign in using LinkedIn. Is there a way to extract token from the response like we do for Facebook and pass it to the backend by making an ajax request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an [example](https://gist.github.com/Hedde/d2e6283d6323032cf201) using the [python-linkedin](https://github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin) library, you could probably do something similar with social auth using its backend/pipeline principle

Comment: I want to pass the linkedin token from front end via ajax call.